# Find process for Window on screen - tool like xwininfo but for Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows

What's a good way to determine which program a particular GUI window belongs to on Microsoft Windows?

On Linux i can use the `xwininfo` command and then click the window.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) has a cross-hair button on the toolbar.

Many other tools can do it including Spy++ and [WinSpy](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy).